# Does $\{x_n\}\xrightarrow wx$ and $\limsup_n\left\|x_n\right\|\le\left\|x\right\|$ imply $\{x_n\}\to x$ in a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $$p_\varphi(x):=\left|\langle x,\varphi\rangle\right|\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$ for $\varphi\in E'$.

> If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$, then it's easy to show that$^1$

1. $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\xrightarrow wx$, then $$\left\|x\right\|_E\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\|x_n\right\|_E.\tag1$$
2. $\left\|x_n-x\right\|_E\rightarrow{n\to\infty}$ if and only if $$\sup_{\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le1}p_\varphi(x_n-x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2.$$

The crucial tool to prove these results is an immediate corollary$^2$ of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Now consider the following assertion:

3. If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\xrightarrow wx$ and $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\|x_n\right\|_E\le\left\|x\right\|_E,\tag3$$ then $\left\|x_n-x\right\|_E\rightarrow{n\to\infty}$.

> $(1)$ and $(3)$ together imply $$\left\|x_n\right\|_E\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\left\|x\right\|_E.\tag4$$ If the norm on $E$ is induced by an inner product, this is enough to ensure convergence in norm, since we can simply write $$\left\|x_n-x\right\|_E^2=\left\|x_n\right\|_E^2-2\Re\langle x_n,x\rangle_E+\left\|x\right\|_E^2\tag5\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.$$

> Does (3.) hold generally?

I could imagine that we can still find a similar identity like $(5)$. For example, in order to prove "$\Leftarrow$" in (2.), we are choosing $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E'$ with $$\langle x_n-x,\varphi\rangle=\left\|x_n-x\right\|_E\tag6$$ and $\left\|\varphi_n\right\|_{E'}\le1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Maybe a similar choice is possible in general.

---

$^1$ Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\xrightarrow wx$ denote the convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to $x$ in the weak sense, i.e. with respect to the topology generated by $(p_\varphi)_{\varphi\in E'}$.

$^2$ If $x\in E\setminus\{0\}$, there is a $\varphi\in E'$ with $\varphi(x)=\left\|x\right\|$ and $\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}=1$.

Comment: No, in $c_0$, look at $(e_1+e_n)$. It converges weakly to $e_1$, but does not converge in norm to $e_1$.

Comment: @Kavi I should have specified $n>1$, above. But regardless, my limsup is 1, no?

Comment: @kavi We are in $c_0$, here.

Comment: I think the argument presented for inner product spaces generalizes to uniformly convex spaces.